# Azure Worker Roles VM instances stops unexpectedly

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I had two worker role instances out of six total in a cloud service stop by themselves, apparently for no reason. In my logs I discovered that a third instance went down one hour earlier (to the minute), for 25 minutes, and then started again. What could have caused this to happen?

The cloud service is four different worker role projects, two of them has two instances each. They all work with Service Bus and either Storage Table, SQL Database or both. The instances that stopped were all from different projects.
They have worked fine before and this particular version has been running until now for six days without any problems.
I checked Windows Azure Service Dashboard and everything looks fine there.
They were not in recycling mode like when there's an unhandled error.

I have uploaded a new version (I was going to anyway, almost the same) and put two instances for each role. Nothing has stopped so far.

In the management portal I don't see a way that someone could do that without stopping the whole service (all instances). Does anyone have an idea to how this could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say that they stopped, what exactly do you mean?  Was the instance gone?  Was it in the Busy state?  What was the exact message in the portal?  How did you recover them?

I suspect when you say stopped you mean the VMs were rebooted unexpectedly and then came back online shortly after that.  If this is the scenario, check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/09/19/role-instance-restarts-due-to-os-upgrades.aspx for information about OS updates in Azure and what you would see in your roles.

Comment: It said "VM stopped" at the two of them and from my logs I could see that a third instance had called OnStop and OnStart (25 minutes later) one hour earlier than I noticed the two others. They did not seem to be rebooting as it simply said they were stopped and nothing else happened. I uploaded a new version and then stopped the running version (I could have just restarted that one, but I was going to update it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Auto Scaling options for your deployment in the Azure Management Portal... are you sure it wasn't just Azure spinning down idle instances to save you on resource consumption ?

Comment: I have not used auto scaling yet, but I plan to. The roles constantly search the Service Bus queues for new items and the Service Bus queues is being filled with new items all the time. One instance that were down had only that one instance of that role running.